# How to set css property using multiple values in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, charts

I have some statistical data e.g. ticketCount and totaTicketCount. I want to display this data by using some charts as shown below and I need to set width property by using its style.

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width: 80%"></div>
```

As this bar displays the count and totalCount values by percentage, I need to set width value using ticketCount / totaTicketCount value. For example 20 / 100 and display the bar as 20% of filled. So, what is a proper way to set this in Angular? I tried `calc()` method but cannot make it work and I am not sure maybe there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's should help by addding [ngStyle]:

```
<div style="background-color: black; width: 100%"  
    [ngStyle]="{'width':ticketCount / totalTicketCount+'%'}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use number it works (`[ngStyle]="{'width': '50%'}"`), if I use variables not works. Any idea?

Comment: Any idea about the solution?         .

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that the initialization of chart js is loaded first and does not see your variables as they are passed after initialization.
Try set variables in the constructor or in `oninit ()`
maybe help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ngStyle`

```
<div class="progress-bar" [ngStyle]="{'width': ticketCount / totaTicketCount +'%'}">
</div>
```

Comment: @Fredrick did this not work.. it should work.